Clang-format is formatting too much
I just installed clang-format and set "Clang format style" to "LLVM". Highlighting a line and running M-x clang-format-region changes the formatting of the whole file.
Also it seems to have changed auto-indentation settings, but I'm not sure.
I want it to do nothing until I explicitly ask it, and stick to only the region when I use clang-format-region.

Is it possible that the formatting is being triggered by some other package like lsp-format or format-all?

clang-format-region looks for a style file, and, if not found, then format the buffer instead. Set clang-format-style to file and add a file .clang-format to your project root folder. That should contain at least a line #Based on style: LLVM.

In terminal clang-format --help will show how to generate your .clang-format file.

@Ian I'm not familiar with the "project" abstraction in this context. What is that?

The 'project folder' is the folder containing your .cpp file. In more complex projects, the project folder may contain some other folders, e.g. local include, src/source, build.
